# Can you add child nodes dynamically with amcharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I was wondering--can you dynamically add/update new children nodes to a Force Directed Tree on amcharts?

Comment: You can change the svg however you feel like.

Comment: I meant these types of graphs: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/force-directed/